# Cчитать введенные пользователем данные у InputEvent firefox

Tags: javascript, input, firefox

Работаю с обработчиком события нажатия (*oninput*).
 Считываю данные, которые вводит пользователь в нужное мне поле с помощью *свойства data объекта inpitEvent*.
  **Проблема** в том, что *в mozila firefox невозможно считать свойства*  InputEvent(он их не поддерживает), такие как data, inputType, а эти жизненно необходимы для работы моей программы.
Может кто знает как это обойти и все-таки считать то что нужно у oninput в firefox? 
Может через какие-то "волшебные хаки"? Или мне нужно менять обработчик событий?
**Важно:** работаю на чистом js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Протестировал в FF. Всё работет корректно. Посмотрите, если вопросы по прежнему есть, то дайте код

```js
var initialUnderscoresLineLength = 0;
var insTextBuffer = "";
var INS_Block = document.getElementsByTagName("ins")[0];

document.getElementById("mainBlock").addEventListener("keypress", insOnKeyPressHandler);
document.getElementById("mainBlock").addEventListener("input", insOnInputHandler);
document.getElementById("mainBlock").addEventListener("paste", insOnPasteHandler);

insTextBuffer = INS_Block.innerText;
function insOnKeyPressHandler(e) {
  console.groupCollapsed("onkeypress event");
  console.log(`input value: ${e.key}`);
  console.log(`content: ${e.target.innerHTML}`);
  console.groupEnd();
}
function insOnInputHandler(e) {
  console.groupCollapsed("oninput event");
  console.log(`content: ${e.target.innerHTML}`);
  console.groupEnd();
}
function insOnPasteHandler(e) {
  console.groupCollapsed("onpaste event");
  console.log(`content: ${e.target.innerHTML}`);
  console.groupEnd();
}
```

```html
<div id="mainBlock" contenteditable="true">
  <ins> текст  1________1  текст</ins>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJKBOx?editors=0010 Вот код

Comment: Ааа, тоесть разговор про `contenteditable` елементы

Comment: знаете как можно исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Я бы сказал что подход к разработке не правильный. Такие евенты слушаются нормально и отрабатывают, а вот `event.data` получить нельзя

Comment: Изменил код для примера. Как я вижу то здесь два варианта. Первый - *использовать `onkeypress` event*. Второй (упоротый) - сохранять текущий контент в переменную -> на `oninput` с помощью regexp сравнивать старый и новый контент и выделять `diff`.